# Excel VBA Error while inserting image to SQL Server database as varbinary(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, varbinary

I'm trying to insert an image into a SQL Server database, into a column of type `varbinary(MAX)`; but no matter what I do I get this error:

> System Error &H80040E14 (-2147217900)

What am I doing wrong? Please help me :-( ...

The SQL statement works fine when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio.

This is my code:

```
Public Sub ExecuteSQL()
    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Connected As Boolean

    DBServer = Sheets("Config").Cells(12, 2).Value
    DBName   = Sheets("Config").Cells(13, 2).Value
    DBUser   = Sheets("Config").Cells(14, 2).Value
    DBPass   = Sheets("Config").Cells(15, 2).Value
    Connected = ConnectToDB(Conn, CStr(DBServer), CStr(DBName), CStr(DBUser), CStr(DBPass))

    SQL =       "INSERT INTO Items (ItemName, Description, Image) "
    SQL = SQL & "VALUES ('Item1', 'This is a test', (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET('C:\Temp\Test.JPG', SINGLE_BLOB) as Rec))"

    RecCount = Query(Conn, SQL, Sheets("SQLResults").Cells(1, 1))
    Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing
End Sub

Function ConnectToDB(Conn As ADODB.Connection, Server As String, Database As String, UserName As String, Password As String) As Boolean
    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    On Error Resume Next
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Server=" & Server & "; Database=" & Database & ";" & "Uid=" & UserName & ";" & "Pwd=" & Password & ";"
    Conn.Open
    If Conn.State = 0 Then
        ConnectToDB = False
    Else
        ConnectToDB = True
    End If
End Function

Function Query(Conn As ADODB.Connection, SQL As String, RangeToPaste As Range) As Integer
    Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
    Dim Field As ADODB.Field
    Dim Col As Long
    Query = 0
    Set recordSet = New ADODB.recordSet
    recordSet.Open SQL, Conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText ' <--- Error Here'
    If recordSet.State Then
        Query = recordSet.RecordCount
        RangeToPaste.CopyFromRecordset recordSet
        Set recordSet = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: can you edit your post with the exact SQL statement you used on the SSMS? Maybe there is a syntax issue. Does vba tell you which line is erroring out?

Comment: Not a SQL server person but does the account the DB runs under have access to the folder where the jpg is stored?

Comment: I think @TimWilliams is on the right lines.  Error codes starting 0x8 are access privilege errors.  Usually these are caused by insufficient rights to open or access a file, but they may be caused by memory access problems (in this case unlikely I think).

Comment: Does the insert work if you set the image-field to `null`?

Comment: The Excat SQL that runs fine on the SSMS is:

INSERT INTO Items
 (ItemName,Description,PriceInDollar,Image)
VALUES
 ('Test Item', 'This is a test', 100.00, (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Test.JPG', SINGLE_BLOB) as Rec))
 
Just to clarify when I run it on th SSMS I use Image that sits on the Server C:\ Drive, and when I use it from my excel it uses Image on My Laptop C:\ Drive so it is not matter of access to the folder or image (that not the issue)

and yes, when I set the Image-Field to NULL it works fine.

Appreciate your support on the issue

Comment: Your SQL server machine has access to your laptop C: drive?

Comment: No the SQL Machine can't access my laptop C: drive, I tried putting the image on a shared folder on the Machine with full access to everyone, and got the same exact error :-( :-( :-(...

Comment: Does the account under which your database runs have access to the shared drive?  It may well be a local account and not a network account...

Comment: Yes, it does. The share drive has full access to everyone.

Comment: "everyone" means all *network* (domain) users but may not include the user account running your SQL server service(s)

Comment: How do I do that? How to I give a SQL Login user, Permissions on Shared Folder?

Comment: That's probably a question for your IT group if you have one.

Comment: Found The Solution and how to do it - Tim & all THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, eventually it was matter of permission (Thanks Tim) I found out that in order that a SQL user will be able to run image query such as Insert and Edit the user should have the server role: bulkadmin.

- On the SSMS Go to --> Security --> Logins --> double click the SQL User
- Select the Server Roles Page
- Check the bulkadmin checkbox.